# Is it possible to generate a nested JSON from a Spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to create a JSON that contains nested fields as such:

```
[
        {
            "name": "field1",
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "name": "field2",
            "type": ["null", "string"]
        },
        {
            "name": "field3",
            "type": "string"
        }
    ]
```

I'm being fed this information from a Spreadsheet doc (Google Sheets). I would think that I'd be able to convert that Spreadsheet info into CSV format, and then transform the CSV to JSON, however I don't think CSV handles these nested JSON formats. I tried and it just leads to malformed JSON.

[image]

Comment: How does the original data look in the spreadsheet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is possible, but edit your question with a mocked version of how your spreadsheet data appears (need to see how rows and columns look).

Comment: I've updated the OP with a screenshot.

Comment: But do you have a sample of how it looks before you tried to convert to CSV? Actual data, but replace sensitive data with generic info.

Comment: I'm directly handed this Spreadsheet by a business team, and then I just export it to CSV

Comment: I'm still not following the process, sorry. So, a business team hands you a spreadsheet with 2 columns and 4 rows? Something seems amiss here. Also, at what point in the process do you add brackets and indent?

Comment: The spreadsheet I'm actually given has more information than this, I can show all of the information but I don't see the point as it's largely the same structure and not a complicated Spreadsheet. Those brackets are already there. I guess the big question is just whether CSV can only export to flat JSON?

Comment: That's what I mean. I'm wondering how it looks in the spreadsheet before you tried exporting to CSV. If the data are already in their own rows and columns, then I think a simple formula would enable you ensure a clean CSV file. But I'm only making assumptions because I'm imagining how the data looks. Without seeing the the actual excel data, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: This is how it looks though, I'm practically handed this exact Spreadsheet, and then in Google Sheets there's a simple export button that allows me to download as CSV.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just want to create a JSON file with this data? What do you want to do with it? Download it? Add it to Drive? How/where are you gonna use it? Are you using Apps Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet transforms the data posted in the screenshot of your question in the desired output:

```
function toJSON(){
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
   const data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();

   var jsonArr = [];

   for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
       jsonArr.push({
           name: data[i][0],
           type: data[i][1]
       });
   console.log(jsonArr)  
}
```

Excuse me in advance if I misunderstood your question.